# Why is the $P(X=x) =0$ when $X$ is continuous?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that if X is continuous, then P(X=x) =0 for any x.

But say we work backwards. Let X be the height of a random individual and after measuring him we find his height to be $x$. Doesn't this contradict the fact that the Probability of X taking on value x is 0?

Isn't this like saying an impossible event has occurred?

Comment: This is why we say that $X\neq x$ **almost surely**. If we have $X\neq x$ in the sense that $X(\omega)\neq x$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ (which is a stronger condition than $P(X=x)=0$) then we are entitled to say that $X\neq x$ **surely** but this terminology is seldom used in probability theory.

Comment: yes im familiar with the almost surely terminology and have always wondered about that. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Continuous probability can be a little unintuitive at first, and is actually a mathematical abstraction that does not perfectly model **any** real world situation. For instance, in your heights example, when we measure someone's height, the measurement apparatus does not tell us an exact real number - instead, it tells us a number like 1.84 meters, which actually means that the true height lies somewhere between 1.835 and 1.845 meters. In this case, the distribution of heights would actually be a discrete probability distribution, and a given interval of heights would be assigned a non-zero probability if and only if there exists at least one person whose height belongs to that interval.

When we simplify our model by ignoring the number of significant digits (or more precisely, by assuming the number of significant digits in our measurement apparatus is quite large), then these intervals become tinier and tinier - from centimeters, to millimeters, to micrometers, etc - until we reach a situation where these intervals are so small compared to the number of individuals that almost none of them are occupied. It is obviously not that useful to have a distribution with so many "holes" like this, and the reason it happened is that we went overboard with our precision - effectively, keeping the number of individuals fixed as we took the limit from the discrete to the continuous.

More commonly, when one uses a continuous distribution (like the normal distribution a.k.a. the bell curve) it is describing an approximation where both the number of individuals and the "bucket sizes" (related to the number of significant digits in the measurement) are being rescaled in such a way that you get an "interesting" limit. There are very technical ways to rigorously say what "interesting" means, but what it boils down to is that each interval of strictly positive length is assigned a strictly positive probability, and each interval of zero length is assigned a zero probability - so probability is roughly measuring the size of a set (the formal explanation is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))). Since any particular number $\{x\}$ describes an interval of zero length (think of the interval $[a,b]$ which has length $b-a$, now set $a=b=x$), it therefore must be a assigned a probability of zero by a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 2):

An event that has probability $0$ isn't necessarily impossible. Just very improbable.

Consider this: pick some insanely huge number $N$. Sample $X$ that many times. Do you actually expect it to be exactly equal to $0$ even a single time? No, you don't. That means the probability that $X=0$ is less than $\frac1N$. This works for any $N$, so the actual probability is $0$.

For instance, I don't expect the height of a single person on this planet to be *exactly* 180cm (that's currently an $N$ of about $7.7$ billion). There could be some that are within an atom's width of 180cm. That's also somewhat improbable, but it has a positive probability. (Humans can't stand  perfectly still, and our bodies change from second to second, so it doesn't really make sense to assign a height to a person this exactly. We disregard that for this example.)

There are so many different numbers that have to share a more-or-less equal probability that that probability simply can't be positive.

Comment: do you mean sample X from uniform (0,N)?

Comment: @Qwertford No, I mean take any continuous $X$, _then_ choose an $N$ and sample from $X$ a total of $N$ times.